# Generics declaration type explanation

Tags: java, generics, scjp

I'm preparing for SCJP see one of the patterns of Generics wildcards and trying to understand how it works

```
public static <E extends CharSequence> Collection<? extends CharSequence> getLongWords(Collection<E> coll)
```

Based on my understanding, the Collection is the parameter that is being used to the method.

There should be a return type to the method but im confused why there is 2 return types -

```
<E extends CharSequence> Collection<? extends CharSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) Documentation, Please read it to understand more. You are not having two return types, it's a generic method

> The syntax for a generic method includes a type parameter, inside angle brackets, and appears before the method's return type. For static generic methods, the type parameter section must appear before the method's return type.